# In Solaris UNIX what is a mountpoint and what makes a mountpoint different than a regular file system?

Tags: solaris, solaris-zones

I don't really know the significance of a mountpoint in UNIX Solaris or what a mountpoint is used for, could someone explain this, what do I have to know about a mountpoint as an administrator?

Answer (score 2):

Mount points in Solaris are the same thing as in Linux, so if you're doing research on this, most information you find regarding Linux should apply.

In Windows, each disk's contents are made available to the Windows OS by creating a drive letter for that drive, like C:  You can then access C:\Windows or D:\MyStuff.  The C: and D: contents are kept separate.

UNIX/Linux filesystems have a single file system.  I'm simplifying some things here, but the contents of a disk are "mounted" into the single filesystem, either at the root "/" directory, or some subdirectory underneath that.  If Windows sees the first and second disk as C: and D:, a UNIX/Linux filesystem might see these as "/" and "/home".  The mounts that are done automatically at boot time are typically listed in `/etc/fstab`.

(Solaris has a very different way of splitting up a disk into smaller "partitions" than Linux uses, anything you see about partitioning for Linux does not apply to Solaris, except that the overall idea of splitting a large disk into smaller partitions is still a thing in both).

While this article focuses on Linux, most of it applies to Solaris.  https://opensource.com/life/16/10/introduction-linux-filesystems